# appending csv file into an empty list in Python 2.7.3 - getting an empty list back

Tags: python, list, csv, append

I'm trying to open a csv file and append rows to a list. I tried a few different things, but I always get back an empty list. Any advice?

```
>>> googleData = []   
dataFile = open("googlePrices.csv", 'rU')  
for row in dataFile:   
    googleData.append(row)

>>> googleData
[]
```

Comment: put a print statement in there right before each append: `print row`. Are you sure you are getting data?

Comment: I just ran your exact code on a csv testfile and it worked. Also, check out the stdlib [cvs module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).

Comment: just checked the file and is where it should be, looks like not opening the file properly for me,but checked the csv in excel and it looks fine,not sure whats going on...

Comment: We have no idea what is going on either. Did you try the print statements I suggested? If it were a problem of not opening properly, you would get an `IOError`

Comment: yep tried that as well but no error, https://www.dropbox.com/s/sz885fohzzj7fga/googlePrices.csv   thats the file i use if anyone could check if it works fine with this code

Comment: thx, when i refer to dataFile i get this: >>> dataFile
<open file 'googlePrices.csv', mode 'rU' at 0x0000000002A1D300> so i guess it's opening the file

Comment: reinstalled python and works fine now :)

Answer (score 0):

A good practice is to read ***each line*** from the CSV or any other file..

a possible solution can be something like this:

```
def main():
        with open('sample.csv' , 'r') as f:
                my_list = []
                for line in f.readlines():
                        my_list.append(line)
                print my_list

if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

***UPDATE :***

Since readlines() reads every line of the file into memory, this answer isn't optimized ..

Comment: -1: `readlines` is *worse* than just iterating through the file object, since it reads every line of the file into memory.

Answer (score 0):

use csvreader http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

```
import csv
csvr = csv.reader(open('googlePrices.csv' , 'r'))
for row in csvr:
   ....
```

Comment: problem was in python ...for some reason exact same code works fine after python reinstall... but still not sure what could cause that...maybe csv library was corrupted. thanks all for help

Answer (score 0):

```py
googleData = []   
dataFile = open("googlePrices.csv", 'rU')  
for row in dataFile:   
    googleData=googleData.append(panda.Dataframe(row))
```

Comment: Please include an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes.